# How do I solve derivative of $(2x^2+x+3)(5x+7)$ using product rule.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

I've to find the derivative of
$$(2x^2+x+3)(5x+7)$$

Using product rule I get
$$(2x^2+x+3)×5+5×(2x^2+x+3)\\20x^2+10x+30$$

Which is wrong. Please help, where I went wrong.

Comment: You got correctly the first part, which is $(2x^2+x+3)\times 5$. The second part which is $5\times (2x^2+x+3)$ is wrong. It should be $(5x+7)\times(4x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

$y=(2x^2+x+3)(5x+7) $ then
$$y'=(2x^2+x+3)'(5x+7)+(2x^2+x+3)(5x+7)'\\
=(4x+1)(5x+7)+5(2x^2+x+3) $$

Answer (score 0):

You used [product rule](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-1/derivative/different-rules-for-derivative/rules-for-derivative) wrong, i.e.,
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(f(x)g(x))=f(x)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}g(x)+g(x)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)$$

Therefore,$$(2x^2+x+3)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(5x+7)+(5x+7)\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(2x^2+x+3)\\=(2x^2+x+3)×5+(5x+7)(4x+1)$$
$$=30x^2+38x+22$$